# When installing laravel-6 framework, `composer global require laravel/installer` gives Permission Denied Error

Tags: laravel, exception, installation, composer-php

I am typing this command in cmd `composer global require laravel/installer`
as typing this command ,this exception appears:

```
[Error Exception]                                                              
file _get _contents (C:\Users\ Boushra\ AppData\Roaming\Composer): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Comment: i guess when u installed composer, php path not configured correctly, or try the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel someproject` instead

Or you can try open the Command as Administrator (Right click in the CMD icon and click Run as Administrator). I prefer the command with create-project.